# Nutch - crawl domain first

Tags: url, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to Nutch and have very and I try to make it do some specific crawling, i.e. I want it to first go e.g 3 levels deep withing one specific domain(e.g. wikipedia) - that part can be achieved by modifying regex-urlfilter file.

But then I want it to start crawling all external links that it fetched before but only with 1 level depth.

So, my question is, is there any way to get list of crawled links from first run so that they could be used as seeds for second crawling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of crawled urls using this command:

```
bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -dump file
```

You can then manually edit the urls/seed.txt file with the output from that command.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your response :) I solved it through running query on solr which returned urls, I forgot I had field <url> that was fetched along with other stuff ;)